# Does minimum rep to answer protected question includes association points?

Tags: support

When I visit this question,
[How do I explain to a six year old why people on the other side of the Earth don't fall off?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94471/)
, I see this message:

> protected by dmckee♦ 2 days ago
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

But I have currently 101 rep points.

After some thinking, I came to the conclusion that my 100 "association bonus" points doesn't count towards this requirement. Is this the reason I can't answer? If it's the case, wouldn't be relevant to let this a little more explicit in the message?

Answer (score 5):

> Is this the reason I can't answer?

Yes.

> If it's the case, wouldn't be relevant to let this a little more explicit in the message?

It is pretty explicit:

> To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation *on this site*.

The reasoning behind this is that when it comes to site-specific policies, someone with 101 rep is not much more knowledgeable than someone with 1 rep. Popular questions tend to attract attention from the network, and most won't know if their answer is really appropriate.

Comment: "It is pretty explicit" Probably to native english speakers, indeed (not my case).

Comment: @Bacco if you can think of a suitable alternative that's clear, concise, and short, then you should post it as a feature request in the [mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's probably just as easy as saying: "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (not including association bonus)"

Comment: And probably make the words "association bonus" a link to somewhere that's defined so people can read about it if they don't know what it is.

Comment: @Bacco no, you're right, it's not at all explicit, even to many/most native English speakers. There is a [request on meta.SO to clarify this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481) which you might want to upvote.

Comment: Don't you earn 100 points on *this site* when you get the site association points? I mean it's not another site that's giving this to you LOL.

Comment: @MikeBrown you can only earn it once on each site. For the first association you'll get it on both sites.