# Message incorrectly claims I need 10 reputation points to answer, when I already have 10 points

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, reputation

I recently wanted to post an answer to this question:

[Is it possible to build a thermoelectric nuclear power plant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191425/)

However, at the bottom of the page, I saw the following notice:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

As far as I can tell, I have 60 reputation, unless I'm misunderstanding what *reputation* means in this context (I clicked on the link to [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and as far as I can tell I'm not).

Note that the "duplicate" post shows a different message. In that message, the intent is clear (you must have *earned* reputation). I got a different, erroneous message.

**UPDATE: posted on Meta SE: [Incorrect wording in protected question status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259878/incorrect-wording-in-protected-question-status)**

Comment: In general, it is possible to get "blocked from answering" if one has a history of bad contributions, but this does not apply in your case. Are you sure you were logged in properly?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes, my avatar appeared at the top of the page with the 60 reputation points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does minimum rep to answer protected question includes association points?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5424/)

Comment: I've changed the question to better reflect that this query is about bug in the documentation, not about the "intended behaviour". Note that the duplicate post shows a different message.

Comment: The new title isn't much clearer, either. This has come up a number of times before and there is no clear solution. The operative words are 'posting an answer now requires 10 reputation **on this site**'. If you feel this documentation should be changed take it up at meta.stackexchange (but be sure to look for duplicates first).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the clear solution is to use a correct description. The current wording is wrong. I'll post it / check on meta SE as you suggest.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. The most contentious text is the `Protected` banner at the top of the thread, which currently reads 'To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site' and it's a lot clearer. The text you came up with is a different instance, but it can probably be fixed by a similar application of the word 'earned'. Put it up at the mother meta, and post the link here.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty posted on meta, thanks for the advice :) It looks like they've recently made the wording change.

Comment: @quant Just to emphasize, "The wording on protected questions" is an ambiguous phrase: there's *two* banners, one at the top and one on the answer box. One is fixed, one is not. Make your MSE question reflect this from the start and you'll get a better reception there.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your [reputation history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/30877/quant?tab=reputation&sort=time) then 51 p comes from 100 p association bonus minus 50 p bounty plus 1 initial p, which do not count as points earned on Phys.SE.

So effectively you have earned 60 p - 51 p = 9 p on Phys.SE. So it seems that you indeed were blocked by the 10 p protection. See also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5424/2451) and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6591/2451) related meta posts.

Comment: The site doesn't say anything about "earned" points, it just says I need to _have_ 10 points, which I unambiguously do. It sounds like a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @quant - Nope, the protection message says (quoting verbatim) - "_To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site._" i.e. **Earned 10 points** is spelt out clearly.

Comment: @TheDarkSide I don't know where you found that but the message I got didn't use those words. See the quote I provided.

Comment: @quant - Please look at [the protection message in the question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191425/is-it-possible-to-build-a-thermoelectric-nuclear-power-plant). i.e. below where it says "_Protected by Qmechanic_". You can find the above quote written verbatim. I don't dispute it, you have hit on a valid point, the message you got while trying to answer, probably needs updating :)

Comment: @TheDarkSide That's interesting. Below where it says "*Protected by Qmechanic*" I see "*Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.*". It looks like we're seeing different messages...

Comment: I've changed the question to better reflect the fact that this is a bug in the documentation.